React Vimeo OnPlay not working as expected
I am using the @u-wave/react-vimeo library and I am having issues relating to passing functions to the Vimeo component. For example, I am passing onPlay function to the component and all it does is console.log some text.  I then check it in the browser console but there is no log.
Here is an example CodeSandbox.
When one clicks the play button I was expecting it to console.log the text provided.  Any help is appreciated.
